# Add 1 second in between array items so that created_at in db aren't all the same, Laravel createMany?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table called `event_speakers`. In the app, a user can click on a `+` icon and add as many speakers as they want.

I'm using a for loop and then Laravel's `createMany` method.
The problem is that the order of the speakers is coming out wrong when I fetch them from the db, and I can't sort them because the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns in the database are all exactly the same.

Is there a way to somehow add a second or a few milliseconds in between each record so that the `created_at` date and time are not all exactly the same?

Here is my code that successfully inserts the data:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $numRecords; $i++) {
    if ($request->speaker_name_en[$i] != null) {
        $data[] = [
            'photo' => $this->uploadImage($livestream, $client, $request['speaker_image_en'][$i]),
            'name_en' => $request->speaker_name_en[$i],
            'name_fr' => $request->speaker_name_fr[$i],
            'title_en' => $request->speaker_title_en[$i],
            'subtitle_en' => $request->speaker_subtitle_en[$i],
            'description_en' => $request->speaker_description_en[$i],
            'title_fr' => $request->speaker_title_fr[$i],
            'subtitle_fr' => $request->speaker_subtitle_fr[$i],
            'description_fr' => $request->speaker_description_fr[$i],
            'client_id' => $client->id
        ];
    }
}
if (isset($data)) {
    $client->eventspeakers()->createMany($data);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I would guess they all have an id. Couldn't you sort by that instead?

Comment: You could also always add another column called `sort` or `sort_id`, and place the value of `$i` in that field.

Comment: Manipulating the `created_at` value to fulfil an ordering requirement feels wrong to me. I would be inclined to implement, and have previously done so, the suggestion from @aynber.

Comment: Thank you aynber, I did a combination of your answer and justrusty's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not orderBy() a different column? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

You could also specify the `created_at` and add a second each iteration

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $numRecords; $i++) {
    if ($request->speaker_name_en[$i] != null) {
        $data[] = [
            'photo' => $this->uploadImage($livestream, $client, $request['speaker_image_en'][$i]),
            'name_en' => $request->speaker_name_en[$i],
            'name_fr' => $request->speaker_name_fr[$i],
            'title_en' => $request->speaker_title_en[$i],
            'subtitle_en' => $request->speaker_subtitle_en[$i],
            'description_en' => $request->speaker_description_en[$i],
            'title_fr' => $request->speaker_title_fr[$i],
            'subtitle_fr' => $request->speaker_subtitle_fr[$i],
            'description_fr' => $request->speaker_description_fr[$i],
            'client_id' => $client->id,
            'created_at' => now()->addSeconds($i),
        ];
    }
}
if (isset($data)) {
    $client->eventspeakers()->createMany($data);
}
```